# table overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three tables in my page....
All the three tables are overlapping....
How to avoid the three tables from overlapping....

http://jsfiddle.net/WG7kk/3/embedded/result/

```
<table id="inventoryTable" class="table dataTable" aria-describedby="inventoryTable_info">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="inventoryListHeading" role="row" style="background-color: #1a4567; color: white;">
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px;">Qty</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 123px;">MFG P/N</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 85px;">Unit Price</th>
                                <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 134px;">Ext. Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                            <tr id="row_1" class="odd">
                                <td class=" "><div id="fdCompanyName_1"><a href="/Customer/index/?step=modify&amp;cid=1">FQ Systems</a></div></td>
                                <td class=" "><div id="fdCustId_1"><a href="/Customer/index/?step=modify&amp;cid=1">1</a></div></td>
                                <td class=" "><div id="fdContactName_1"><a href="/Customer/index/?step=modify&amp;cid=1">Soojin Kim</a></div></td>
                                <td class=" "><div id="fdPhone_1"><a href="/Customer/index/?step=modify&amp;cid=1">408-172-3827</a></div></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically there's nothing wrong with your table. It must be your CSS. Use a tool like Firebug to help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Woah. Classic example of 'divitis" waaaaay too many divs in the html at fiddle. You have a table inside a div and div's inside of table cells.

While that can work, why not just put id's on the td instead? Are you at the mercy of some CMS?

Also, I see this ID: fdContactName_1 twice just scanning over the code. ID should only appear once per page.

I suggest first copying all code, pasting it in at the validator: validator.w3.org/

Fix all errors and see if you can structure the content better. Right now, from the fiddle code there are 82 Errors, 45 warning(s). The warnings won't matter as much.

Even using something like table margin:0 0 30px 0; gets into trouble because of all those id's...the specificity is going to be a nightmare to get well-formed

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. Your tables are bigger then the div containing them. Try setting a width to your table. Edit : Actually, remove the div span5 in your other div since your table is suppose to resize to the size of your div and the div in which it is right now is breaking out of your other div.

Also you have waaaayyy too many divs that are useless. Like Kelly Johnson said. a single div inside a td isn't really usefull. Same with span5 inside span6.

You have to see all the elements as containers. Div is a container used for styling purpose and placing stuff around your page. Basically, div is a rectangle. You don't need a rectangle inside your rectangle. If you need space between text and the side of a td, use the style padding.